# Android Listview with EditText and Action Button

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I have got a Listview and I want that a text from an EditText will be
added to a ListView when I click an ActionButton.

I tried to manage it this way, but it does not work:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Activity3 extends Activity
{
    ListView HeldenList;
    EditText FigurVaule;
    Button save;

    List<String> HeldenListString = new ArrayList<String>();

  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act3);

    HeldenListString.add("Hello World");

    HeldenList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.HeldenListe);
    FigurVaule = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.menu.save);

    HeldenList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, HeldenListString));
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View currentView) {
            HeldenListString.add(new String(FigurVaule.getText().toString()));
        }
    });
  }


  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu paramMenu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.save, paramMenu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(paramMenu);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      switch(item.getItemId()) {
      case R.menu.save:
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
          this.startActivity(intent);



          break;
      default:
          Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
          this.startActivity(intent1);
      }

      return true;
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for my bad English (I'm from Germany).

Comment: you need to notify the adapter that the underlying data has changed. I recommend keeping a reference to the arrayadapter and using the arrayadapter.add method instead, as it already contains the call to notifyDataSetChanged.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it to the ArrayAdapter. Something like this should work:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, HeldenListString);
HeldenList.setAdapter(adapter);
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View currentView) {
        adapter.add(new String(FigurVaule.getText().toString()));
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm... now the app crashes as soon as it switches to activity3

Comment: What's the stack trace there? Hopefully you can get some clue from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, HeldenListString);
HeldenList.setAdapter(adapter);
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View currentView) {
        adapter.add(new String(FigurVaule.getText().toString()));
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }
});
```

I hope it useful to you.